# Java 8 , Merge two or more nested list

Tags: java, arrays, merge, java-8, nested

I need to merge inner/nested array :

**Pojo structure**

**Requirement** : How can I  achieve in java 8  if there are 2 lists or X number of list to merge? What is the easiest way to merge nested array ?

```
private class Student {
    private int studentId;
    private List<Marks> markList = new ArrayList<>();
}

private class Marks {
    private Integer subjectId;
    private String subjectName;
    private Integer mark;
}
```

Need to merge below 2 records:

```
{
  "studentId": 1,
  "Marks": [
    {
      "subjectId": 1,
      "mark": 10
    },
    {
      "subjectId": 2,
      "mark": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "studentId": 1,
  "Marks": [
    {
      "subjectId": 1,
      "mark": 15
    },
    {
      "subjectId": 3,
      "mark": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Giving the final expected result as :

```
{
  "studentId": 1,
  "Marks": [
    {
      "subjectId": 1,
      "mark": 25 //Addition of record 1 and 2
    },
    {
      "subjectId": 2,
      "mark": 10
    }
    {
      "subjectId": 3,
      "mark": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried first. Post an [mcve].

Comment: Best solution is to use maps and merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map each student by their id with the terminal operation `collect(Collectors.toMap())`, then handling the collision cases to merge your different instances of student into a new one.

At that point, when instancing a new `Student`, you could implement a nested stream to merge the marks of the two colliding instances. By applying a second `collect(Collectors.toMap())`, you could group the marks by the subject id and then handling once again the colliding cases by merging the marks' value.

In the snippet below, I've enriched your test case by adding a second `Student`:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Student(1, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Marks(1, 10), new Marks(2, 10)))),
        new Student(1, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Marks(1, 15), new Marks(3, 10)))),
        new Student(2, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Marks(1, 5), new Marks(2, 10)))),
        new Student(2, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Marks(2, 5), new Marks(3, 10))))
));

//Temporary map
Map<Integer, Student> mapTemp = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getStudentId,                                        //grouping by student id
                Function.identity(),                                                            //setting as value the student
                (s1, s2) -> new Student(s1.getStudentId(), new ArrayList<>(                     //Creating a new Student whose list of marks is given by the merged marks of the two colliding students
                        Stream.concat(s1.getMarkList().stream(), s2.getMarkList().stream())     //Chaining the two lists of marks into a single stream
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Marks::getSubjectId,                  //Grouping by the marks by the subject id
                                        Function.identity(),                                    //Setting as value the mark
                                        (m1, m2) -> new Marks(m1.getSubjectId(), m1.getMark() + m2.getMark())))  //Handling the colliding marks by summing them together
                                .values())))                                                    //Retrieving the collection of merged marks
        );

//Result list with the merged students
List listRes = new ArrayList(mapTemp.values());
System.out.println(listRes);
```

Here there is also a link to test the code above:

https://ideone.com/0i6ZqG

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using nested lists, the best way to approach the solution will be using `MAP`.

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(new Student(1,new ArrayList<Marks>(){{
            add(new Marks(1,10));
            add(new Marks(2,8));
        }}));
        studentList.add(new Student(1,new ArrayList<Marks>(){{
            add(new Marks(1,5));
            add(new Marks(2,8));
            add(new Marks(3,6));
        }}));
```

You can add more students and their marks for more testing.

The main objective would be to calculate each subject's mark for each individual student and store it into a `Map` object.

```
       //Storing the latest merged marks for each students .
        Map<Integer,List<Marks>> listMap = new HashMap<Integer,List<Marks>>();
        for(Student student: studentList){

            if(!listMap.containsKey(student.getStudentId())){
                listMap.put(student.getStudentId(),student.getMarkList());
            }else{
                /** storing individual marks of each subject for this student
                 * <k,v> = <SubjectID ,Marks>
                */
                Map<Integer,Integer> merge = new HashMap<>();

                // storing existing marks of any subjectID.
                for(Marks oldMark : listMap.get(student.getStudentId())){
                    merge.put(oldMark.getSubjectId(),oldMark.getMark());
                }
                // calculating new marks as per each subject id
                for(Marks newMark : student.getMarkList()){
                    // checking whether subject has any old values or not .
                    int val = merge.get(newMark.getSubjectId()) == null ? 0: merge.get(newMark.getSubjectId()) ;
                    merge.put(newMark.getSubjectId(),val+newMark.getMark());
                }

                //creating new merged marks list
                List<Marks> temp = new ArrayList<Marks>();
                for(int sid : merge.keySet()){
                    temp.add(new Marks(sid,merge.get(sid)));
                }
                // updating the main map with new merged values
                listMap.put(student.getStudentId(),temp);
            }
        }
```

Once you get your final merged map you can convert the same to a Student type of list if needed.